# Error while online manipulation of CM5 in the bioloid kit

Tags: microcontroller, atmega

I am getting the following error after flashing a program on the controller(CM5) and while on-line manipulation of CM5 in the bioloid kit.

---

### 000 0x00 dynamixels found . Error 0800.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first suspect in this case is the loose wiring as happened to me once.